# why is it showing cannot convert FILE to constant char for argument 1 to int printf error?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *p;
    char c;
    p=fopen("sach","r");
    printf("\n File contents are:");
    while((c=getc(p))!=EOF)
    {
        printf(p);
    }
    fclose(p);
    getch();
}
```

```
11  11  E:\software\sachin C\read file.cpp  [Error] cannot convert 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int printf(const char*, ...)'
```

This is the error i got when compiling.

Comment: When you open a file, you use `fopen`. When you close a file, you use `fclose`. When you read a character from a file, you use `fgetc`.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to print the value of `c` instead? If so, try looking at the documentation of `printf`. A viable format string would be either `"%d"`, if you want the numerical value, or `%c`, if you want the 'character code'. If you really want the address of your file pointer, you may want to try `%p`.

Comment: `printf(p)` -> `printf("%c", c)`. What do you expect `printf(p)` to do?

Comment: BTW: after `p = fopen("sach","r");` you should check if `p` is NULL and act accordingly. The `sach` file might not exist.

Comment: Also note another bug: getc() returns an int, so it must be `int c`. Then the proper definition of main is `int main(void) { ... }`.

Comment: Sachin Jose, What do you want `printf(p);` to print?  Do you want it to print the character  `c`?

Comment: Yes i want to print the characters in file name "sach"

Answer (score 0):

For displaying text content, may try to change your while loop to:

```
while((c=fgetc(p))!=EOF)
{
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

Comment: To display the char code, use printf("%i ",c);

Comment: Thank you s much sftac gsv..got it cleared